# Opening workbook from file and updating link in original workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a macro in VBA, that will open another Workbook using a PathFile specified in a cell (this works), updates link in workbook in which macro is used (doesn't work) and closes the PathFile workbook (works)
This is a code:

```
Sub UpdateRaw()

Dim CurrWb As Workbook    
Dim FilePath As String
Dim book As Excel.Workbook

Set CurrWb = ActiveWorkbook
FilePath = Range("I1").Value

Dim app As New Excel.Application
app.Visible = True 'so we can see whether correct file is being opened

Set book = app.Workbooks.Open(FilePath)

CurrWb.Activate
Worksheets("Raw_vs_Actual").EnableCalculation = False
Worksheets("Raw_vs_Actual").EnableCalculation = True

book.Close SaveChanges:=False
app.Quit
Set app = Nothing

End Sub
```

Going step by step I found that command CurrWb.Activate doesn't take me back to my original Workfile. My suspicion is that by opening new Excel Application I can't get back to the CurrWb (ActiveWorkbook). Is there a workaround? I need this so my INDIRECT function doesn't return #REF.

I'm using Excel 2010 in case it's important.

Answer (score 1):

I think Set book = app.Workbooks.Open(FilePath) shall be enough, but if not refresh the workbook:

```
book.RefreshAll
```

for opened workbook. For the workbook that contains the macro, use

```
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
```

Comment: I need to refresh formulas for the workbook I'm using macro in and not the one that is being opened.

Comment: if so, use ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

Comment: It turns out that EnableCalculation doesn't work in Excel 2010. Also opening workbook it the same application as original workbook automatically refreshes all the formulas referencing workbook. Thanks for help though.